# Responder perguntas que foram negativadas, é ruim?

Tags: debate

[Não consigo executar DELETE no SQL quando submeto form via POST no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13161/nao-consigo-executar-delete-no-sql-quando-submeto-form-via-post-no-php/13167#13167)

Essa pergunta foi mal formulada (talvez por falta de conhecimento do OP), mas respondi pois consegui entender o que ele queria, como podem perceber a pergunta recebeu 3 votos negativos, minha resposta que foi escrita corretamente para solucionar o problema também recebeu voto negativo, o que minha resposta tem que levou a isso? Ou é apenas um senso comum negativar respostas para perguntas que não tem qualidade para incentivar respostas para perguntas bem formuladas?

Comment: Uau, -2... Pessoalmente, só faço isso quando é uma pergunta *flagrantemente* off-topic e/ou quando a resposta é "toma esse código e me dá 10 pontos aí". Neste caso, acho que vale a pena dar uma editada na pergunta usando informações que o OP postou como comentários.

Comment: @brasofilo Concordo. eu vejo que tem muito "maria vai com as outras no site", tem gente que vai no automático para votar ou fechar algo só porque alguém o fez antes. Eu tenho votado negativo em bastante pergunta porque vejo baixa qualidade ou falta de esforço em muita coisa. Posso errar às vezes, mas eu analiso antes de votar, não voto porque alguém votou. Eu costumo esperar, dar a oportunidade de melhora, principalmente antes de votar para fechar algo que não está claro. Prefiro salvar mais que fechar. Mas não vou editar assunto que eu não posso melhorar. E não vou salvar o insalvável.

Comment: Essa pergunta é "salvável" - eu só voto negativamente em uma pergunta quando acho que a pergunta não pode ser salva nem com edição. Já sua resposta está ótima, tome meu +1 lá.

Comment: as vezes respondo por impulso sem querer.. depois que posto eu vejo que tem negativo... mas aí eu deixo quieto.

Answer (score 18):

quando estou a fim de ajudar o autor não me importo se a pergunta foi negativada, se é *off-topic*, etc - primeiro tomo uma ação (comentar, votar pra fechar) e depois respondo. Em geral, não recebo nada por isso - nem positivo nem negativo - mas tenho observado aqui no SOpt muita gente votando negativo em respostas a perguntas ruins.

Não me lembro de já ter visto esse comportamento no SOen. Aliás, lembro de ter lido alguém se referir ao SO como "o lugar onde encontro respostas brilhantes pras minhas perguntas idiotas", ou algo do tipo... Na minha opinião, se a resposta é boa, deveria sem bem avaliada ou - no máximo - *não* avaliada (ex.: quando a pergunta é off-topic, não faz sentido recompensar quem responde).

É uma situação semelhante a sugerir uma edição: se um autor sempre formula mal a pergunta, e alguém sempre aprimora ela, ele não tem incentivo pra se esforçar em fazer perguntas melhores. Por outro lado, se a pessoa tiver boa vontade, o simples exemplo alheio pode ser um estímulo para ele melhorar. No fim, não há uma resposta "certa" entre editar ou não editar (mas a tendência é estimular a melhora). Da mesma forma, há prós e contras em se responder perguntas ruins.

Sei que isso não respondeu muita coisa, mas pelo menos serve como base pra uma argumentação... Na minha opinião *pessoal*, a resposta é **não**, não é ruim responder perguntas ruins.

Answer (score 13):

Concordo com tudo o que disse o mgibsonbr. Vou colocar aqui minha postura pessoal.

**Eu não respondo perguntas fechadas ou negativadas.**

Mas é tudo preto no branco assim: Claro que não. Muitas vezes a pergunta está sendo injustiçada. É raro, mas acontece. Não é o caso de os casos recentes postados aqui no meta, mas existem casos que as pessoas não entendem do assunto e acabam errando na moderação.

Nestes casos eu poderia responder, mas antes ou concomitantemente **eu tentaria salvar a pergunta**, não só votando, tentando reabrir, mas editando, comentando, indo no chat e talvez até abrindo uma discussão no meta. Até porque se realmente eu acho que estão tomando a atitude errada com a pergunta, seria bom que todos aprendessem para não repetir o erro, inclusive eu mesmo, porque posso estar errado e a pergunta pode ser ruim mesmo.

Eu vejo casos de fechamentos por duplicação que não são realmente duplicadas e principalmente casos de "não está claro o que está sendo perguntado" em que foram equivocados ou pelo menos precipitados. O último caso costuma acontecer muito porque a pessoa que está votando não entende do assunto, aí se ele não tem subsídio suficiente ELA não entende o que está sendo perguntado e a culpa não é da pergunta.

Mas ressalto que apesar de que seria melhor que não acontecessem, esses casos são raros.

Eu já negativei uma ou duas respostas no site quando a pergunta era muito ruim. Veja que é raro eu fazer isso. Eu negativei a resposta porque a pergunta é ruim? Não! A resposta era ruim também. Na verdade poderia ter negativado mais porque é bastante comum (mas há exemplos do oposto) a resposta à uma pergunta ruim atrair ruim também.

Comment: Acontece muito de uma pessoa não saber o nome do que que ela precisa, nesse caso é bom editar a pergunta e adapta-lo para o contexto correto, certo? Como a pessoa é a nova ela pode não conhecer o termos e ficar meio vago a forma dela se expressar, não?

Comment: @NULL Na pergunta, sem dúvida. Mas se for resposta, já tenho dúvidas, porque se a pessoa não sabe bem do que está falando, aí provavelmente não deveria responder.

Comment: Sim, na pergunta, até porque não tem sentido pegar algo pra responder se você não tem o mínimo conhecimento do que se trata.

Comment: @NULL pena que nem todo mundo tem essa percepção e responde o que não sabe mesmo assim :)