# Pergunta camaleão - Era sobre proxy reverso e agora é sobre download de vídeos do youtube

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Tive um problema em [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96385/132). O usuário postou a seguinte pergunta:

> ## cURL proxy reverso
>
> Meu problema é o seguinte, minha curl requisita uma informação, mas ela teria que ser feita com o ip do usuária que a fez.
>
> Seria possível com proxy, ou teria que ser outra solução?
>
> [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [curl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl) [proxy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proxy)

A pergunta estava mal-escrita, mas eu "entendi" (SQN) o que ele quis dizer, editei a pergunta para "consertá-la" e postei uma resposta.

Ocorre que nos comentários da resposta, ficou bem claro que ele se expresssou muito mal na pergunta e acabou perguntando algo totalmente diferente do que ele queria.

Então eu pedi para ele fazer uma outra pergunta. O motivo era para evitar ter um caso de uma pergunta camaleão aonde o texto final não tinha nada a ver com o texto original. A pergunta foi fechada.

E então ele postou [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96484/132) que depois foi deletada por ele mesmo (o link só é visível para o próprio autor, os moderadores e quem tiver pelo menos 10 mil pontos de reputação).

Ele voltou nessa primeira pergunta e a editou pesadamente, tornando-a em algo que não tem quase nada a ver com o que a pergunta era originalmente (e acredito que deve ter sido orientado a fazer isso), sendo portanto um caso extremo de pergunta camaleão. Observe como ela está agora:

> ## Script Youtube Downloader
>
> Olá Guilherme Nascimento, acredito que toda critica nos ajuda a evoluir.
> Não sei se serei claro o suficiente mas toda via eu irei editando ate ficar claro.
> Vamos ao problema.
> O script funciona bem, faz o que promete, mas o problema é o youtube, quando o script esta na hospedagem ele também funciona, desde que os pedidos de download sejam poucos, quando a um grande volume de pedidos, eles são bloqueados, então fui descobrir o porque, quando é requisitado o arquivo info ele é gerado com o ip do servidor, e eu acredito que a solução seria achar uma forma para que tudo fosse feito com o ip do usuário, foi ai que eu achei um site que faz isso, então acredito que seja possível só não sei como fazer.
>
> Segue o link do script e do site que faz o que eu preciso.
>
> Script: https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader
> Site: http://convert2mp3.net/
>
> Obs: A parte da conversão para mp3 eu não tenho interesse.
>
> [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [curl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl)

Uma vez que a pergunta agora não tem nada a ver com o que ela já foi antes e se tornou em uma pergunta completamente diferente, a minha resposta não tem mais sentido nenhum pois não tem mais nenhuma relação com o que a pergunta é neste momento. A pergunta está sendo reaberta.

Com certeza fui precipitado em responder, reconheço isso. Entretanto, aqui vão meus questionamentos:

- Fui correto em orientá-lo a criar outra pergunta ao invés de editar a pergunta original tornando-a em algo completamente diferente da original? Uma coisa é editar a pergunta para corrigir uns probleminhas, outra coisa é reescrevê-la do zero e fazer uma pergunta completamente diferente no final.
- Ele foi correto ao excluir essa outra pergunta?
- Ele foi orientado a excluir essa outra pergunta?
- Permitir esse nível extremo de pergunta camaleão é adequado?
- A pergunta deve ser reaberta?
- Devo deletar a minha resposta?
- O que mais deu errado?
- O que mais deve ser feito?

Comment: Eu acho que se devia reverter a pergunta e o AP se quiser pode fazer outra. Não se pode invalidar uma resposta porque o AP decidiu que afinal quer saber de outra coisa.

Comment: Bem eu reverti para a última versão e editei para incluir a pergunta inicial. O que acham?

Comment: Acho que já me arrependi.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sei lá o que fazer com esse caso. Agora temos três perguntas no total. Além disso preferia que essa situação fosse resolvida por alguém que seja neutro no meio disso tudo, por isso não editei mais nada desde então e me abstive de tomar mais ações no caso.

Comment: Victor eu achei que podia resolver o caso, mas acho que piorei.

Comment: Eu excluí uma delas (a duplicata exata). A outra pra mim também parece duplicata @JorgeB.

Comment: Não estou entendendo a necessidade de outra pergunta. A sua resposta já disse muito. Só que boa parte do que você disse (ou tudo) é coisa que ele não deve saber implementar.

Comment: Victor, estou conferindo a meta-tag [meta-tag:pergunta-camaleão] e parece que foi você quem criou. Pensei em fazer a curadoria (resumo de tag e taguear outras 4 perguntas) mas estou na dúvida se realmente a tag merece ser criada (no meta.se e meta.so não existe)... o que acha, @bfavaretto? . . . . Sobre esta pergunta específica, acho que merecia [meta-tag:pergunta-zorra-total] :D

Comment: @brasofilo Bem, sim, eu criei a tag, pois vi que já havia outras questões do tipo aqui, e acho que outras surgirão no futuro. Entretanto, esqueci de aplicar a tag às demais questões.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Me desculpem se eu fiz algo errado, ainda não sei bem como fazer as perguntas corretas.
Pois bem o que devo fazer, preciso de orientação para não cometer mais o mesmo erro.

Grato a todos.

Comment: Sempre que tiveres uma nova dúvida que seja muito diferente da pergunta que já fizeste convém criares uma nova pergunta para que as respostas não fiquem invalidas. É somente isso.

Comment: Certo.
É que sou novato no site e em programação, então eu estou meio perdido.
E agora o que devo fazer, já que eu fiz tudo errado, como eu posso prosseguir com minha duvida?

Comment: Rafael copia a pergunta que tens agora e faz uma nova, eu depois reverto essa para a original.

Comment: Certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 11):

> Fui correto em orientá-lo a criar outra pergunta ao invés de editar a pergunta original tornando-a em algo completamente diferente da original? Uma coisa é editar a pergunta para corrigir uns probleminhas, outra coisa é reescrevê-la do zero e fazer uma pergunta completamente diferente no final.

Não tenho certeza. Se a pergunta original estiver no escopo e não se enquadrar em nenhum critério de fechamento então ela *não deve* ser substancialmente modificada de modo a invalidar as respostas existentes. Mesmo que a dúvida real do autor seja outra, a pergunta e suas respostas continuam sendo potencialmente útil, e não devem ser invalidadas.

O que complica a situação é que não só a mesma foi fechada como você foi um dos que votou para fechar. Isso sinaliza que não estava claro para você também o que estava sendo perguntado, e você optou por responder em bases incertas. [Na minha opinião](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1250/215) ([não unânime](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1251/215)) não há problemas em fazer isso, mas você precisaria arcar com o risco da sua resposta não se adequar à pergunta - adaptando ou excluindo se necessário.

Dito isso, o fato da edição ser *radical* - e não meramente um esclarecimento acerca da pergunta original - invalida esse raciocínio. É um caso semelhante a [mudar a pergunta para oferecer rápido uma recompensa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4448/215) - a intenção conta, e o fato da pergunta já ter resposta (ainda que em bases incertas) seria um motivo extra para *não* substituir uma pergunta por outra.

(Resumindo: se você achou que a dúvida real do autor era bastante diferente do que foi perguntado a princípio, você foi correto sim em orientá-lo dessa forma. Mas o "ao invés de" não estaria 100% incorreto dependendo das circunstâncias.)

> Ele foi correto ao excluir essa outra pergunta?

Nem correto nem incorreto, ele está simplesmente confuso com a utilização do site, talvez tratando-o como se fosse um fórum... (sua mensagem de "pergunta relacionada" pode tê-lo feito pensar que havia duplicado um tópico já existente - o que na concepção dele seria inaceitável e precisaria ser removido)

> Ele foi orientado a excluir essa outra pergunta?

Não vejo evidência nenhuma de orientação. Suspeito que tenha agido pela cabeça dele (ver parêntese acima).

> Permitir esse nível extremo de pergunta camaleão é adequado?

Não. Tenho [a mesma opinião do bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4457/215), se a pergunta não tivesse resposta (e eu acrescentaria também "sem comentários" - pois a mera *tentativa* de ajudar o autor pode agregar valor à pergunta original) não haveria problema, mas com uma pergunta camaleão [por definição] não é esse o caso.

> A pergunta deve ser reaberta?

Não. Quem está votando pra reabrir deve estar se guiando somente pela revisão atual, sem perceber o quanto ela mudou em relação à revisão anterior. Eu reverteria essa edição radical antes que ela fosse reaberta (mas não vou fazer isso agora já que o caso está em discussão).

> Devo deletar a minha resposta?

Seu critério. Se você acha que ela agrega valor ao site (não posso opinar - tldr num assunto que não domino) sugiro *não apagar*. Os dois votos positivos mostram que outras pessoas também a acharam útil.

> O que mais deu errado?

Nada, só mais um usuário novo se habituando ao site. SNAFU...

> O que mais deve ser feito?

Sugiro consertar a pergunta primeiro (revertendo a edição radical), depois restaurar a pergunta removida e talvez mover o conteúdo novo pra lá, e por fim se dirigir ao usuário novo *lá* (respondendo e/ou orientando quanto ao uso do site, conforme o possível/necessário).

(Já votei para restaurar a pergunta, se discordarem de mim favor ignorar)

Comment: Bem, na verdade eu dei o último voto de fechamento depois que eu orientei a fazer uma nova pergunta, vez que pela discussão dos comentários ficou claro que ele perguntou a coisa errada.

Comment: "Eu reverteria essa edição radical antes que ela fosse reaberta (mas não vou fazer isso agora já que o caso está em discussão)." exatamente o que eu faria. E acho que é o que deve ser feito.

Comment: Perfeito. Concordo plenamente.